# La clase "Input" no existe en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity2d

Acabo de empezar a aprender a usar Unity y C#, ahora mismo mi meta es hacer que el personaje que tengo en 2D se mueva con las teclas, pero cuando quiero escribir Input.GetAxisRaw no me aparece nada, como si no existiera la clase "Input"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float horizontalInput = 0f;
    public float speed = 5f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")
    }
}
```

Hasta ahora no he encontrado a nadie más con un problema similar y tengo miedo de que haya tocado algo que no debía y ahora no me aparezca por eso:(

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar que no hay ningún problema con paquetes del registro de Unity o código local yendo a la consola en el editor de Unity y verificando que no haya errores persistentes de compilación como esto (Puede variar según el error que hubiera):

[image: Error en consola]

En caso de que Unity no te muestre errores revisa que tengas instalada la carga de Visual Studio con soporte para Unity que incluye **Visual Studio Tools for Unity**, esto lo encuentras en Visual Studio Installer, selecciona modificar tu instalación de Visual Studio y selecciona en las cargas de trabajo "Desarrollo de juego con Unity".

[image: Instalador de Visual Studio]

Si la carga de trabajo ya está instalada asegúrate que tengas la última versión del paquete de Visual Studio Editor en tu proyecto de Unity, ya que los proyectos nuevos de Unity por default usan una versión vieja que puede tener errores. Para actualizar el paquete, dentro del editor de Unity ve a **Window** > **Package Manager** y asegurate que en el menu al lado del botón de suma en la cabezera de la ventana del administrador de paquetes diga "Packages: In Project", dentro de la lista a la izquierda deberías ver hasta el final un paquete llamado "Visual Studio Editor", seleccionalo y en la barra de botones en la esquina inferior derecha selecciona **Update**, en caso de que no te aparezca una actualización revisa que tengas seleccionada la versión 2.0.11+ (Al momento), una vez se instale deberías de ver algo así (Imagen tomada de Unity 2021.1.16f1):

[image: Administrador de paquetes con última versión de Visual Studio Editor]

Adicionalmente para revisar que Unity este detectando tu instalación de Visual Studio puedes acceder a preferencias usando la cabezera del editor de Unity, dando click en **Edit** > **Preferences** luego en el menú de preferencias accedes al apartado de **External Tools**:

[image: Menu de preferencias]

En este menu te debería de aparecer en "External Script Editor" el nombre completo de Visual Studio y su versión, si te aparece algo como devenv.exe o no te dice algo como "Visual Studio Editor vX.X.XX enabled" en la parte de abajo del selector, quiere decir que Unity no está conectando con Visual Studio para generar los proyectos C# de tu proyecto de Unity y para generar el IntelliSense. Puedes intentar cambiar el selector para ver si aparece tu versión de Visual Studio disponible:

[image: Versiones de Unity detectadas]

Sino, puedes probar seleccionando en **Browse...** y yendo a la ruta de instalación de Visual Studio y seleccionando devenv.exe.

Si Unity detecta tu instalación de Visual Studio y el paquete de conectividad (Visual Studio Editor), puedes borrar los proyectos de C# (.csproj) de la ruta de tu proyecto de Unity y seleccionando la opción **Regenerate project files**, con esto Unity volvera a generar los proyectos usando la instalación de Visual Studio que seleccionaste en el selector.

Si nada de lo anterior funciona te recomiendo levantar un bug yendo a **Help** > **Report a Bug...**:

[image: Reportar un error]

Con esto obtendrás soporte directo de Unity sobre la integración ya que en mi caso he tenido problemas similares con el paquete de Visual Studio Editor que solo se han resuelto hasta reportar el bug y obtener una actualización.